# $34!=295232799cd96041408476186096435ab000000$, find $a$ ,$b$, $c$, and $d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

There was a number theory question that I have to do for homework.

> $34!=295232799cd96041408476186096435ab000000$, find $a$ ,$b$, $c$, and $d$

I know $b=0$ because $10^7\big|34!$ only. But how can I find other variables?

Remark:

No electronic calculation device can be used for calculation. (I need to write the full solution.)

Can someone help me?

Comment: The rule for divisibility by $3$ tells you that the sum of the digits is divisible by $3$ (same for $9$ and for $27,$ with $27$ including the other results, so maybe just use the rule for $27)$ and the divisibility by $11$ rule tells you that the alternating sum of the digits is divisible by $11.$ This gives you $2$ linear equations in $4$ unknowns, so you'll need to look at other divisibility rules or something else --- maybe knowing that the solution can only be digits $0$ through $9$ will be enough when you have those two equations.

Comment: also, if I'm correct $34!/10^7$ is a multiple of $4$, so $a=2$ or $a=6$. Am I right?

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: try also divisibility by $8$, using $5a0$, so that you might be able to fix $a$. Then divisibility by $3$ and $11$ should suffice, as per @DaveL.Renfro comment.

Comment: "No electronic calculation device can be used" ... But is the computer you use to talk to us not an example of an electronic calculation device?

Comment: I can prove that $d=3$ and $a+c=2$ and by the dfnu's hint we can get the answer.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Rule for $27$? What is that?

Comment: You can also use divisibility by $1001=7\times 11\times 13$ if you need as well as powers of $2$ and $3$ (the zeros cover $5$)

Comment: @TonyK: Oops! I was thinking that the rule for $3$ and $9$ continued for higher powers of $3$ (as is the case for divisibility by powers of $2),$ but I looked at some notes of mine where these are proved, and the method of proof doesn't work for $27$ (relies on powers of $10$ being one more than a multiple of $9$). Moreover, simple examples shows the analogous rule doesn't work --- the sum of the digits of $27$ (or of $2700,$ or of $8100,$ etc.) is not divisible by $27.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing $b=0$ and $\frac{34!}{10^7}$ being a multiple of $8$, the last three non-zero digits $35a$ must be divisible by $8$, so $a=2$ for sure. Now set up linear equations modulo $9$ and $11$ (this is just a digit sum and alternating digit sum, and I learned this from studying the Trachtenberg system a long time ago) and we get
$$d+c\equiv3\bmod9$$
$$d-c\equiv3\bmod11$$
since $9,11\mid34!$ By trial and error we see that $d=3$ and $c=0$, so the solution is $\overline{abcd}=2003$.

Answer (score 1):

Sum of digits is divisible by $9$, which gives
$$a+c+d\equiv5(\mod9).$$
$$2-9+5-2+3-2+7-9+9-c+d-9+6-0+4-1+4-0+8-4+7-6+1-8+6-0+9-6+4-3+5-a\equiv0(\mod11),$$
which gives
$$a+c-d\equiv-1(\mod11).$$
From here we can get $a+c=2$ and $d=3$.

Now, since $a\in\{2,6\}$, we obtain $a=2$, $c=0$ and we are done!